# Convert an array of variable length strings to dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe

I have an array of variable length strings in each row, where the column labels are indicated in the string content. However, the columns are variable in size and may be large in size. How do I convert this format to dataframe?
For example

Input:

```
np.array([['Hour: 1', 'Name: EVENT_1', 'Column1: A'],
      ['Hour: 2', 'Name: EVENT_2', 'Column1: B','Column2: BCX'],
      ['Hour: 2', 'Name: EVENT_2', 'Column1: C','Column3: BCY','Column4: BCE'],
      ['Hour: 4', 'Name: EVENT_4','Column1: D',  'Column3: BCZ'],
      ['Hour: 5','Name: EVENT_5','Column2: BC', 'Column99: BCR' ,'Column100: BCA']
     ])
```

expected output:

```
Hour |  Name     |Column1|Column2|Column3|Column4...Column99|Column100
1    |  EVENT_1  |  AA   | BCX   |       |       ...        | 
2    |  EVENT_2  |  BQ   |       |       | BCE    ...       | 
3    |  EVENT_3  |  CW   |       | BCY   |       ...        | 
4    |  EVENT_4  |  DF   |       | BCZ   |       ...        |   
5    |  EVENT_5  |       | BC    |       |       ...    BCR |   BCA
```

Comment: I'd suggest looping over the data and separating the column names from their data (creating `dict`s), and passing the result to the DataFrame constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Ola and welcome to Stack Overflow

AS @jirassimok mentioned you need to iterate to construct a dictionary. Here is a piece of code that could help:

```py
#Array to collect all rows
new_array=[]
#For every row
for r in rows:
    #Array to collect new row
    new_row={}
    #For every "column: value" pair convert to dictionary
    for c_v in r:
        #Add all values to their column
        new_row[c_v.split(': ')[0]]=c_v.split(': ')[1]
    new_array+=[new_row]
pd.DataFrame(new_array)
```

If you really need to save space, you could convert the above to a single line using *dictionary and list comprehension*

```py
pd.DataFrame([{x.split(': ')[0]:x.split(': ')[1] for x in r} for r in rows])
```